# conntrack events(conntrack -E) show 0.0.0.0 as source and destination addresses

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, conntrack, nf-conntrack

These are the logs down below.

```
[DESTROY] udp      17 src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=3 bytes=216 [UNREPLIED] src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=0 bytes=0
    [NEW] udp      17 30 src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 [UNREPLIED] src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0
    [NEW] udp      17 30 src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 [UNREPLIED] src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0
[DESTROY] udp      17 src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=1 bytes=71 [UNREPLIED] src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=0 bytes=0
[DESTROY] udp      17 src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=1 bytes=229 [UNREPLIED] src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=0 bytes=0
[DESTROY] udp      17 src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=1 bytes=32 [UNREPLIED] src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=0 bytes=0
[DESTROY] udp      17 src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=1 bytes=32 [UNREPLIED] src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sport=0 dport=0 packets=0 bytes=0
^Cconntrack v0.9.13 (conntrack-tools): 7 flow events have been shown.
```

**kernel Version**: 2.6.34

**Library Used/Version**: libnetfilter_conntrack.so.3.0.0

**Dynamic Modules inserted**: lsmod | grep conn

```
nf_conntrack_netlink    14931  0 
nfnetlink               3836  3 nf_conntrack_netlink,nfnetlink_queue
nf_conntrack_sip       19872  1 nf_nat_sip
nf_conntrack_h323      49589  1 nf_nat_h323
nf_conntrack_pptp       4910  1 nf_nat_pptp
nf_conntrack_proto_gre     3910  1 nf_conntrack_pptp
nf_conntrack_ftp        6023  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack_amanda     2673  1 nf_nat_amanda
nf_conntrack_irc        4197  1 nf_nat_irc
nf_conntrack_tftp       3825  1 nf_nat_tftp
```

**Builtin modules**:cat /lib/modules/linux-2.6.34/modules.builtin | grep conn

```
kernel/drivers/connector/cn.ko
kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_ipv4.ko
kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko
```

although I can see the SRC and DST ips in the /proc/net/nf_conntrack and /proc/net/ip_conntrack

I've posted the same question in StackOverflow but got no response. I'm hopeful , Ill get some reply here

Comment: You are using a tool with a [version from 2009](https://git.netfilter.org/conntrack-tools/tag/?h=conntrack-tools-0.9.13) with a [kernel from 2010](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tag/?h=v2.6.34): afaik this falls into not reasonable information technology management practices (even 2.6.34.15 which doesn't appear to be the one you are using was EOL in 2014). You should upgrade kernel and conntrack tools (and thus the whole OS) to check if the problem is fixed first. Nobody can fix a problem on such old software.

Comment: I can understand, but I can't help it. All the other packages will have a dependency issue if I try to upgrade the platform.

Comment: Try at least to upgrade conntrack. The kernel appears to have the correct information - at least somwhere - from what you wrote, so upgrading conntrack could be worth a try. If it's a bug, you can't get a solution on serverfault for this beside upgrading.

Comment: Also beware of a certain class of incompatibility/bug in some APIs: 64 bits kernel with 32 bits userland.